# Why Angular JS “ng-repeat” is not working?

Tags: angularjs

I have this owl crousal :

```
<section id="intro">
                    <div class="sm-holder">
                        <div class="sm">
                            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h1>
                        <span class="year">2020</span>
                    </h1>
                    <div class="owl-carousel owl-intro owl-loaded owl-drag">
                        <div class="owl-stage-outer">
                            <div class="owl-stage"
                                style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0.25s ease 0s; width: 21010px;">

                                <div class="owl-item cloned active">
                                    <div class="item" style="background: url(../Administration/MainPageHeader/camels1.jpg)">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="owl-item cloned">
                                    <div class="item" style="background: url(../Administration/MainPageHeader/camels5.jpg)">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="owl-counter"></div>
                </section>
```

it work ok.

noW

I need to make it dyanmic.

i want to rpeat

and changing camels1.jpg based on value from DB.

I have created angualr app.

in my scope

I have

```
  $http.get('http://192.168.1.40/Test/Apis/GetHeaderImages.ashx')
                .then(function (response) {
                        $scope.headerImages = response.data;
                        var arr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                        $scope.headerImages = arr2;
                });
here headerImages = 0: {Id: 5, ImageUrl: "camels7.jpg"} 1: {Id: 6, ImageUrl: "20202902051438KC.jpg"}
```

I did

## أهلاَ بكم في
                        
                        إتحاد سباقات الهجن
                        
                        2020

```
         <div class="owl-carousel owl-intro owl-loaded owl-drag">
                    <div class="owl-stage-outer" >
                        <div class="owl-stage" 
                            style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0.25s ease 0s; width: 21010px;"id="owl-stage">
                             <div class="owl-item cloned"    ng-repeat="x in headerImages" >
                                <div class="item" style="background: url(../Administration/MainPageHeader/{{x.ImageUrl}})">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              
                </section>
         <div class="owl-counter"></div>
```

Comment: use class active it is missing from the code

Comment: still issue @ShashanSooriyahetti

Comment: you can create a https://plnkr.co/ and attach it here. so it would be easy for others to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

got it working with asp.net tags

```
 <div class="owl-carousel owl-intro">
                                  <div class="item" style="background: url(../Administration/MainPageHeader/camels5.jpg)"></div>
                                <%foreach (var item in imagesUrl)
                                    {%>
                          
                                 <div class="item"  style="background: url(<%=item %>)">

                                </div>
                     <%

                                    } %>
                           </div>
                    <div class="owl-counter"></div>
```

so  ng-repeat was not repeating dives

Answer (score 0):

You should assign it to `$scope.headerImages` rather than `headerImages` in API callback.

```
$scope.headerImages = arr2;
```

Comment: Do not find any other place has issue, maybe you can update the question with '$scope.headerImages = arr2;' and wait for others to solve it.

Comment: ok if  I append $( ".owl-stage").append( "<div class='owl-item cloned active'><div class='item'  style='background: url(../Administration/MainPageHeader/camels7.jpg')></div></div>"); is this good

Comment: You are using jQuery to append, which is not recommended when you are using AngularJs

Comment: any other soultions

Comment: Your previous AngularJs code should work, If you can reprodcue the issue in plnkr or stackblitz, i can continious help you.

Comment: mybe I can use other option

Comment: can not produce stackblitz